# Не обновляется layout при замене фрагмента, но class запускается

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Добрый день, в прошлом проекте я спокойно заменял фрагмент кодом:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getApplication(), SecondFragment.class.getName());
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentview, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Но в новом проекте это не работает, ошибок никаких не выдает.

Хочу заметить, что сам класс `SecondFragment` запускается, но `Loayout` в котором (`R.id.fragmentview`) не обновляется, остается старый фрагмент.

Уже 5 часов смотрю туториалы, пробую разные коды, но ничего не помогает.

В чем проблема?

Может есть другой способ замены и перезагрузки класса фрагмента?

Comment: Есть ощущение, что он тупо не находит R.id.fragmentview.

Comment: Но если запускаю: Fragment myFrag = (Fragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentview); и ft.hide(myFrag);, то он скрывается, получается так его находит. Я в замешательстве.

Comment: Судя по коду всё правильно. Видать у вас какая-то особенность. Может вы фрагмент во врагмент добавляете? Или у вас `ViewPager` задействован?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , ViewPager не задействован. Фрагмент в Layout выглядит вот так: http://cs627331.vk.me/v627331197/2a978/esy7DNoeNV0.jpg . На счет добавления фрагмента в фрагмент я не до конца понял, я же использую replace.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ваша (точнее гугловая) проблема в том, что изначальный фрагмент вы ставите прямо в разметке, а не в коде. Т.е. это баг. Попробуйте изначальный, первый фрагмент убрать из разметки и добавлять его методом `add` из кода.

Comment: Если вы про android:name="com.myapps.myapps.PropertyView",  tools:layout="@layout/list_property", то без них вообще нельзя, начинает ругаться Preview, но скомпилировать можно, после запуска приложения сразу выбивает ошибку: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapps.myapps/com.myapps.myapps.MenuView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class fragment, 27 строка это <fragment

Comment: @developer, я имею в виду, что нужно **вообще** убрать фрагмент (сам его тег) из разметки. И добавлять его только в коде в контейнер. И превью тоже, кстати, аццки глючное. Им лучше вообще не пользоваться. Совсем.

Comment: Спасибо, да, вы были правы, вы красавчик. :)